# Check if service started with Windows on boot

Tags: .net, windows, service

Is there any method to check if our service application is started on boot (it's started automatically with Windows) or it's started manually by someone turn it on ?

Because: I want to do some action when Windows start, like run an application or write log that Window is started..., I don't want it occurs when users just restart the service.

Comment: I guess you could configure the service to not accept stop requests.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thank you but I still want allow users to restart my service in some case

Comment: You've got two separate bits of functionality, then - the stuff you only want to happen on system startup, and the rest.  This might be best handled by having two separate services.  (It could still be a single executable.)  Or depending on your needs you could have the users pause and continue your service instead of stopping and starting it.  I'm  not aware of any other way to tell why Windows is starting your service.

Answer (score 0):

Use command like:

```
sc qc "OneSyncSvc_12e036a"
```

There will be output START_TYPE (2 is AUTO_START)

Comment: Thank you, but this is used to check how service is installed. I mean how to detect if my service is actually started by Windows on boot or it's manually started by someone (because users can run the command net stop/net start to restart my service) and of course START_TYPE is always 2 in both case so i cannot rely on it.